# Multiple forms from single partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a single form partial:

```
<% form_remote_for(@snapshot_comment, :html => { :class => "snapshot_comment", :id => "snapshot_comment" }, :auth_key => params[:auth_key]) do |f| %>
 some stuff...
      <span class="button"><%= f.submit 'Submit &raquo;' %></span> 
      or <a href="#" class="cancel">cancel</a>

<% end %>
```

It gets input into tooltips into a page multiple times via jQuery (targeting snapshot_id).  This works well:

```
//Insert class and partial by targeting snapshot id
$j('<div class="info"><%= escape_javascript(render :partial  => "snapshot_comments",
                       :locals => {
                       :snapshot => @snapshot,
                       :comments => @comments
                       })
     %></div>').appendTo("#slide_<%= @snapshot.id %>");
```

The partial (snapshot_comments) contains the code for the form:

```
<%= render_snapshot_comment_form_for snapshot %>
```

The problem is that when data gets posted - it posts as many times as there are forms on the page.

So If a user enters info and clicks submit --- the content is inserted in every tooltip rather than just the tooltip it belongs to.  I am using Qtip2.

Is there a way to submit the form specific to the tooltip it resides in?

Answer (score 1):

If the form is being rendered multiple times per page from the same partial, then it sounds like your element IDs are the same from form to form within that page.

If your elements don't have unique IDs, then the response gets put into each place where that ID appears.

For example - if you have a page that puts results into a div with an id of "output", and that div gets rendered from a partial 5 times (each time with the same id of "output"), then you're going to see the response rendered 5 times.

Do a "view source" on your resulting page, and look for duplicate IDs, and see if that's the case.